# how we can use mvi architecture

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I implement the Model-View-Intent (MVI) architecture in my Android app to enhance UI development?

I'm relatively new to implementing architectural patterns and have been exploring MVI for improving the UI of my Android application. However, I'm unsure of the steps to effectively integrate MVI into my project. Could someone provide guidance or a step-by-step approach on how to incorporate MVI architecture into my app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.